# Confusion with stateful widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was learning Flutter and came across stateful widgets which looks like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
 }
```

The above code confused me a bit and thus I would like to ask some questions. Firstly, I got that when we setState is called it changes the state and ensures that `build()` method is invoked again. Also, I understood that this code `_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();` is called only once and is it true that that code allows to create initial state or..? Secondly, why do we need to use generics here `State<MyHomePage>` what role does genetics play in here? Lastly, when `build()` method is called again after the invocation of setState, how does `MyHomePage` know that state was updated?

Answer (score 0):

A `stateful widget` is implemented by two classes: a `subclass of StatefulWidget` and a `subclass of State`.

> **The `state` class contains the `widget’s mutable state` and the `widget’s build() method`.**
>
> **When the `widget’s state changes`, the state object calls `setState()`, telling the framework to redraw the `widget`.**

**More Explanation**

> A stateful widget is dynamic: for example, it can change its appearance in response to events triggered by user interactions or when it receives data. Checkbox, Radio, Slider, InkWell, Form, and TextField are examples of stateful widgets. Stateful widgets subclass StatefulWidget.
>
> A widget’s state is stored in a State object, separating the widget’s state from its appearance. The state consists of values that can change, like a slider’s current value or whether a checkbox is checked. When the widget’s state changes, the state object calls setState(), telling the framework to redraw the widget.

To read more about `stateful widgets` in Flutter, check the links below:

[Stateful Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

[Flutter Stateful Widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: sorry just have two questions, Is it true that every time state changes createState is called which then calls _MyHomePageState()? Secondly, which state management can you recommend for Flutter, I found Fish Redux and Moor for sqlite. Are they ok to be used? if not, what do you personally use? Thank you

Comment: The framework calls createState() when it wants to build the widget which then called `_MyHomePageState`. For State management, the Flutter team recommends using the `Provider` package. @SAM

Comment: @SAM: Create state only called when you are rendering widget first time not when you change the state.

Comment: @jitsm555, ok but pls can you tell me if createState is called only once then how MyHomePage know that state was changed? From where MyHomePage get fresh content with changed state? Just this question.

Comment: The `createState` is called only when the `Widget` first build. The `HomePage` rebuilds using the `build` method anytime `setState` is called. @SAM I hope this answers your question

Comment: @SAM: Flutter is not designed that whenever we change the state in setState()-- This will trigger build method.  Only impacted widgets will get rerender

Comment: Noo @jitsm555. The `build` method is rebuilt WHENEVER `setState` is CALLED. Read more about documentation on `setState` please.

Comment: @T.TSage, the documentation says that "if a StatefulWidget is removed from the tree and later inserted in to the tree again, the framework will call createState again to create a fresh State object". Does it mean that when state changes createState is called again?

Comment: `createState` is not called again when `state` changes. It is only called once when the `Widget` is first built @SAM

Comment: When `state` changes,(by calling `setState `), it notifies the `framework` that the `internal state` of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the` framework` to schedule a `build` for this `State object`.

This causes the `build` method of the `state` object to be `rebuilt` @SAM